# Remove rows to the nth position if it found continuous NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am facing a situation where I need a help. I am using the SQL Server 2014.

My query is that I have to remove the NULL valued rows but only if it found in continuous from the starting like below I am giving some Input and Output samples.

```
Sample Input 1 :
```

[image]

```
Sample Output 1 :
```

[image]

```
Sample Input 2 :
```

[image]

```
Sample Output 2: (because from the starting it doesn't have null values. Null values are in the middle)
```

[image]

```
Sample Input 3:
```

[image]

```
Sample Output 3: (it will return blank table as all the null values get removed)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if there are 2 starting nulls, then one value and then another null value? Would you just want the first nulls removed?

Comment: What do you meant by "From the Starting"? First entry of a particular date, first instance for a particular user??

Comment: @JaviTorre Only StartTime can have NULL value. So, if there are 2 records and both have NULL in StartTime then both should be removed but if the 1st row don't have NULL and the 2nd row have NULL then it displays as it is. (See Sample Input and Output 2).

Comment: What if 1,2,4 are not null and 6 is null?

Comment: @PankajSanwal "From the Starting" means row 1 to the nth where it will get the NULL in StartTime but only in continuous. If not null in the row 3 StartTime then it will remove the starting 2 rows because both rows have null.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Provide data as text, not images, and add DDL for the table. What have you tried?

Comment: @Stu If 1,2,4 are not null then it will show table as it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67827507/8483417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not SQL Server, but may give you a hint on how to proceed. Count the null values ordered (summing 0 if null) and then get rid of the ones being 0.

```
with aux (id, v) as (
    select 1, null from dual union all
    select 2, null from dual union all
    select 3, 2 from dual union all
    select 4, null from dual union all
    select 5, 2 from dual),
aux1 as (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN v IS NULL THEN
                    0
                ELSE
                    1
            END
        ) OVER(
        ORDER BY
            id
        ) h1
    FROM
        aux a
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux1
where h1>0;
```

Output:

```
ID  V   H
---------
3   2   1
4       1
5   2   2
```

Comment: `from dual` is not SQL Server syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following. You can run each scenario in SSMS.

**SCENARIO ONE**

```
DECLARE @data table ( InstanceID int, [TimeStamp] datetime, StartTime datetime );
INSERT INTO @data VALUES
    ( 1, '08/22/2020 07:06:00', NULL ), 
    ( 2, '08/22/2020 12:30:00', NULL ), 
    ( 4, '08/22/2020 14:32:00', NULL ), 
    ( 6, '08/22/2020 17:13:00', '08/22/2020 17:30:00' );

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ) AS id,
        InstanceID,
        [TimeStamp],
        StartTime
    FROM @data
)
SELECT
    InstanceID, [TimeStamp], StartTime
FROM cte
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN cte.id = 1 AND cte.StartTime IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN cte.id = 1 AND cte.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        WHEN cte.StartTime IS NULL AND ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM cte AS c WHERE c.id < cte.id AND c.StartTime IS NOT NULL ) > 0 THEN 0
        WHEN cte.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS Exclude

) AS x
WHERE
    Exclude = 0
ORDER BY
    [TimeStamp];
```

**RETURNS**

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| InstanceID |        TimeStamp        |        StartTime        |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|          6 | 2020-08-22 17:13:00.000 | 2020-08-22 17:30:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**SCENARIO TWO**

```
DECLARE @data table ( InstanceID int, [TimeStamp] datetime, StartTime datetime );
INSERT INTO @data VALUES
    ( 1, '08/22/2020 07:06:00', '08/22/2020 07:06:00' ), 
    ( 2, '08/22/2020 12:30:00', NULL ), 
    ( 4, '08/22/2020 14:32:00', NULL ), 
    ( 6, '08/22/2020 17:13:00', '08/22/2020 17:30:00' );

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ) AS id,
        InstanceID,
        [TimeStamp],
        StartTime
    FROM @data
)
SELECT
    InstanceID, [TimeStamp], StartTime
FROM cte
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN cte.id = 1 AND cte.StartTime IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN cte.id = 1 AND cte.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        WHEN cte.StartTime IS NULL AND ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM cte AS c WHERE c.id < cte.id AND c.StartTime IS NOT NULL ) > 0 THEN 0
        WHEN cte.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS Exclude

) AS x
WHERE
    Exclude = 0
ORDER BY
    [TimeStamp];
```

**RETURNS**

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| InstanceID |        TimeStamp        |        StartTime        |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|          1 | 2020-08-22 07:06:00.000 | 2020-08-22 07:06:00.000 |
|          2 | 2020-08-22 12:30:00.000 | NULL                    |
|          4 | 2020-08-22 14:32:00.000 | NULL                    |
|          6 | 2020-08-22 17:13:00.000 | 2020-08-22 17:30:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**SCENARIO THREE**

```
DECLARE @data table ( InstanceID int, [TimeStamp] datetime, StartTime datetime );
INSERT INTO @data VALUES
    ( 1, '08/22/2020 07:06:00', NULL ), 
    ( 2, '08/22/2020 12:30:00', NULL ), 
    ( 4, '08/22/2020 14:32:00', NULL );

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ) AS id,
        InstanceID,
        [TimeStamp],
        StartTime
    FROM @data
)
SELECT
    InstanceID, [TimeStamp], StartTime
FROM cte
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN cte.id = 1 AND cte.StartTime IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN cte.id = 1 AND cte.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        WHEN cte.StartTime IS NULL AND ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM cte AS c WHERE c.id < cte.id AND c.StartTime IS NOT NULL ) > 0 THEN 0
        WHEN cte.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS Exclude

) AS x
WHERE
    Exclude = 0
ORDER BY
    [TimeStamp];
```

**RETURNS**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| InstanceID | TimeStamp | StartTime |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* scenario 1 */
declare @t table ( InstanceID int, [TimeStamp] datetime, StartTime datetime );
insert into @t values
    ( 1, '08/22/2020 07:06:00', null ), 
    ( 2, '08/22/2020 12:30:00', null ), 
    ( 4, '08/22/2020 14:32:00', null ), 
    ( 6, '08/22/2020 17:13:00', '08/22/2020 17:30:00' );

with t_cte as (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by InstanceID) rn,
           sum(case when StartTime is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by InstanceID) is_null
    from @t)
select *
from @t t
where not exists(select * 
                 from t_cte tc
                 where tc.InstanceID=t.InstanceID
                       and rn=is_null);
```

```
InstanceID  TimeStamp                   StartTime
6           2020-08-22 17:13:00.000     2020-08-22 17:30:00.000
```

```
/* scenario 2 */
declare @t table ( InstanceID int, [TimeStamp] datetime, StartTime datetime );
insert into @t values
    ( 1, '08/22/2020 07:06:00', '08/22/2020 07:06:00' ), 
    ( 2, '08/22/2020 12:30:00', null ), 
    ( 4, '08/22/2020 14:32:00', null ), 
    ( 6, '08/22/2020 17:13:00', '08/22/2020 17:30:00' );

with t_cte as (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by InstanceID) rn,
           sum(case when StartTime is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by InstanceID) is_null
    from @t)
select *
from @t t
where not exists(select * 
                 from t_cte tc
                 where tc.InstanceID=t.InstanceID
                       and rn=is_null);
```

```
InstanceID  TimeStamp                   StartTime
1           2020-08-22 07:06:00.000     2020-08-22 07:06:00.000
2           2020-08-22 12:30:00.000     NULL
4           2020-08-22 14:32:00.000     NULL
6           2020-08-22 17:13:00.000     2020-08-22 17:30:00.000
```

```
/* scenario 3 */
declare @t table ( InstanceID int, [TimeStamp] datetime, StartTime datetime );
insert into @t values
    ( 1, '08/22/2020 07:06:00', null ), 
    ( 2, '08/22/2020 12:30:00', null ), 
    ( 4, '08/22/2020 14:32:00', null ), 
    ( 6, '08/22/2020 17:13:00', null );

with t_cte as (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by InstanceID) rn,
           sum(case when StartTime is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by InstanceID) is_null
    from @t)
select *
from @t t
where not exists(select * 
                 from t_cte tc
                 where tc.InstanceID=t.InstanceID
                       and rn=is_null);
```

```
no rows returned
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Uncomment the sample you want to test.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SampleTable    TABLE 
        (InstanceID int, TStamp datetime, StartTime datetime)
;
INSERT INTO @SampleTable
VALUES  
/**/
        (1, '8/22/2020 07:06', NULL)
    ,   (2, '8/22/2020 12:30', NULL)
    ,   (4, '8/22/2020 14:32', NULL)
    ,   (6, '8/22/2020 17:13', '8/22/2020 17:13')

/*
        (1, '8/22/2020 07:06', '8/22/2020 07:06')
    ,   (2, '8/22/2020 12:30', NULL)
    ,   (4, '8/22/2020 14:32', NULL)
    ,   (6, '8/22/2020 17:13', '8/22/2020 17:13')
*/
/*
        (1, '8/22/2020 07:06', NULL)
    ,   (2, '8/22/2020 12:30', NULL)
    ,   (4, '8/22/2020 14:32', NULL)
*/
;
DECLARE @FirstInstanceIsNull bit 
    =   CASE WHEN (
                    SELECT  TOP 1 StartTime 
                    FROM    @SampleTable 
                    ORDER BY InstanceID
                 ) IS NULL 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END
;
SELECT  *
FROM    @SampleTable
WHERE   (@FirstInstanceIsNull = 0 )
    OR  (@FirstInstanceIsNull = 1 AND StartTime IS NOT NULL)
```